# Page Not Found (404) Error in simple Django 2.2 application

Tags: python, django

I used the official [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/) to create this code and I consistently get a 404 error when I put localhost:server/polls/ in the search bar. I followed the tutorial pretty much identically but it still doesn't seem to work. Anyone know a solution to get text displayed at localhost:server/polls/ or at localhost:server?

polls/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(response):
    return HttpResponse('Polls')
```

polls/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns =[
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

Error message:

**Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: admin/
The current path, polls/, didn't match any of these.**

I have looked at lots of different potential solutions and none of them seem to work. Please let me know if you need more info/code, thanks

Comment: Check: `127.0.0.1:8000/polls`

Comment: Still got the same error

Comment: Have you added your app in setting.py?

Comment: make sure your runserver reloads or you can try to restart.

Comment: I've added the app name under installed_apps prior to posting this question

Comment: I've reloaded it multiple times and restarted a few times too, should i delete those files as they could interfere perhaps?